# do_execve() code in linux source code

Tags: linux

In `do_execve()` there is a call to `prepare_bprm_creds(bprm)` in line number 1396.
In `prepare_bprm_creds(struct linux_binprm *bprm)` function definition it calls `prepare_exec_creds()` in line number 1121.
Could you please explain to me the working of `prepare_bprm_creds(struct linux_binprm *bprm)` (what it does).

Comment: Which source file?  Which kernel version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, please cite filename and version number, not just line number. Better yet, link to a LXR listing. In any case...

[prepare_bprm_creds](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.37/fs/exec.c#L1121) eventually calls [prepare_creds](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.37/kernel/cred.c#L283), which allocates a [struct cred](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.37/include/linux/cred.h#L116) - this will eventually hold the security context of the new task (ie, per-thread security information). Along the way, execution also passes through [prepare_exec_creds](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.37/kernel/cred.c#L330), which allocates a [thread_group_cred structure](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.37/include/linux/cred.h#L83), which holds some security information that is shared for all threads in a process.

Note that this only allocates memory for the structure; the new credentials are set in [prepare_binprm](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.37/fs/exec.c#L1205) later.

Answer (score 0):

As for credentials, there is documentation at [Documentation/credentials.txt](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/Documentation/credentials.txt).